# how to show listview data in diff pages using jquery-mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

i m giving my code below.here f is the id of the list.from server i m getting data like profile name,its images and description.so in output as my json data is in array from , i am showing this data in the same page.but i want to show this data like first profile name,its images  and description means array of [0] th element, then some arrow and after that informataion of second profile[1st] element then after second then third on diff pages

```
$('#f').append(
    '<li>'+ '<a>'+
    '<h4>'+ profiles.pName  +'</h4>'+
                     '<img class="imagesize" src="'+ imgurl +'" >' +
                     '<p align="left">'+profiles.about+'</p>'+
                     '<input type="button" value="" background-color="green" id="button" onClick="">'+'</input>'+
                   '</a>' +'</li>'

           );
});
```

pls help me as i m new to this jquery mobile